# OMP loop dependency -

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I try to parallelize the following code

```
double a = 1.5;
double b = 2.5;

double *arr = ...;

for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
{
    arr[i] = b;
    b *= a;
}
```

I have tried different constellations of `private` / `lastprivate` / `firstprivate`

e.g.

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(arr) firstprivate(a, b)
```

but I don't get the right result (comparing to the sequential run)

Comment: Just a quick think I spotted.. Maybe also make `i` private?

Comment: nope. Actually it looks like I am lacking one last iteration.
Sequential I get: 

1.020201360204773
Parallel I get: 1.0000000099999999

Comment: Because of the dependancy, this cannot be parallelized.

Comment: ...unless you manually distribute the iterations to the threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume first you want to avoid the obvious solution where the recurence on `b` is removed:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(c)
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    c = b * pow(a,(double)i);
    arr[i] = c;
}
```

Because of the dependency, your initial code can not be parallelized like this. You have to determine the initial value of `b` for each thread according to the first iteration it handles (this requires a test inside the loop, not very good for the performances) AND assume that a given thread will execute a contiguous range of iterations (probably a `schedule(static,M)` clause can do, where `M = (N-1)/(nbthreads)+1`)

```
int nbthreads, M;

#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(b)
{
    #pragma omp single
    {
        nbthreads = omp_get_num_threads()
        M = (N-1)/nbthreads + 1
    }
    bool first=true;
    #pragma omp for schedule(static,M)
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
       if (first) {
           b *= pow(a,(double)i);
           first = false;
       }
       arr[i] = c;
       b *= a;
    }
}
```

The right solution actually consists in manually distributing the iterations to the threads, so that you know in advance what is the first iteration of each thread:

```
int N=1234, M, nbthreads;
double b=2.5, a=1.5;

#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single 
    {
        nbthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        M = (N-1)/nbthreads + 1;
    }
    int it = omp_get_thread_num();
    int lb = it*M;     // lower bound for the iteration in this thread
    int ub = (it+1)*M; // upper bound ...
    if (ub > N) ub = N;

    b = b * pow(a,(double)lb);
    for (int i = lb; i < ub; ++i) {
       arr[i] = b;
       b *= a;
    }
}
```

Comment: The overall idea is good, but the last for is dangerous and not needed actually. Indeed, `omp for` is meant to share the work but there is no need for that because you already manually determine the begin/end iterator per thread. AFAIK, this causes an undefined behaviour to add the `omp for` in this case though compiler could actually generate a correct code by just ignoring the directive. Besides, there are missing semicolons and I do not understand the purpose of the first 3 lines : `nbthreads` should be private so not accessible outside the parallel section. Did you miss braces?

Comment: You're absolutely right for the last `omp for`, I left it by mistake. I'm going to delete it. I didn't test the code, actually. As for the first 3 lines it's OK without brace, but indeed `nbthreads` has to be declared beforehand.

Comment: @PierU Note that in your last 2 examples nothing guarantees that the number of threads will be equal in the 2 parallel regions. You should use one parallel region only.

Comment: @Laci OK, although it's highly unlikely that it happens in practice... using `omp_get_max_threads` in the first region and forcing the number in the second region should be also OK ?

Comment: I agree that it is very unlikely, and if you use `omp_set_dynamic(0)`, I think the number of threads should always remain the same. Moreover, you have to use `omp_set_dynamic` also if you want to force the number of threads used.

Comment: I have edited the examples to match your remarks